# SASS Variable within string

Tags: css, sass

Hi all I'm new to SASS (late I know) and playing around with mixins.

Basically is there a way to link a variable to a string here is what I'm trying to do but it throws errors.
(This is a condensed version)

```
@mixin post-link ($class, $color, $hover) {
    a.$class:link {
        color: $color;
    }
    a.$class:hover {
        color: $hover;
    }
}
```

Link I say this is a little simpler than what I am trying to do in the mixin (more variables in full one).

EDIT: should add i'm using Compass.
Thanks

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes, you just have to use [variable interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_). Example:

```
@mixin post-link ($class, $color, $hover) {
    a.#{$class}:link {
        color: $color;
    }
    a.#{$class}:hover {
        color: $hover;
    }
}
```

Example on SassMeister: http://sassmeister.com/gist/9533103

The key is adding `#{` and `}` around your variable names to get them expanded.